# AWS json output parsing

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to parse a json out of AWS query. I am trying to get the `RedrivePolicy.deadLetterTargetArn`

So, if I just do:

`--output text --query "Attributes.RedrivePolicy"`

Output: 
`{"deadLetterTargetArn":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:xxxxxx:cloud-us-east-2-deadletter","maxReceiveCount":4}` which is right

when I go to next level:

`--output text --query "Attributes.RedrivePolicy.deadLetterTargetArn"`

It says `None` in output.

Please find my json herein:

```
{
    "Attributes": {
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible": "0", 
        "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"custodian-notify-subscription\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"AWS\":\"*\"},\"Action\":\"SQS:SendMessage\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:xxxxxxxx:cloud-us-east-2\",\"Condition\":{\"ArnEquals\":{\"aws:SourceArn\":\"arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxx:cloud-us-east-2-notify\"}}}]}", 
        "MessageRetentionPeriod": "86400", 
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed": "0", 
        "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxx:cloud-us-east-2-deadletter\",\"maxReceiveCount\":4}", 
        "MaximumMessageSize": "262144", 
        "CreatedTimestamp": "1561753144", 
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessages": "0", 
        "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "10", 
        "DelaySeconds": "0", 
        "KmsDataKeyReusePeriodSeconds": "300", 
        "VisibilityTimeout": "600", 
        "LastModifiedTimestamp": "1561753144", 
        "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:xxxxxxxx:cloud-us-east-2"
    }
}
```

Comment: "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxx:cloud-us-east-2-deadletter\",\"maxReceiveCount\":4}", is in quotes so Attributes.RedrivePolicy returns  string not json. for that you need to parse string into json or simply remove quotes.

Comment: I don't know how AWS work but you can request "Attributes.RedrivePolicy" then parse it into JSON and then request the JSON created

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- A JMESPath query on a JSON string will not produce the expected result if you try to run a query against it using the `--query` keyword in AWS CLI
- In the example provided, the JMESPath query does not work as expected, because the JSON element being queried is technically a JSON string (aka scalar) and not a JSON object (aka dictionary)

### Detailed Answer

- The key to understanding why the example is not producing the desired outcome is in distinguishing a JSON `string` element from a JSON `object` element.
- We provide some examples below with an extremely simplified JSON scenario that helps illustrate what is going on here.

#### Example 01

- In this example, we use JMESPath to query JSON. We get the expected result because we are querying against a JSON `object` element.
- A more detailed description: We have a top-level json `object` with a single name-value pair.

  - The name in the name-value pair consists of the string "Message"
  - The value in the name-value pair consists of a JSON `object`

    - Digging deeper, the JSON `object` has two name-value pairs

```js
        // Original JSON
        {
            "Message": {"Greeting":"Hello","Audience":"World!"}
        }

        // JMESPath query 
        --query 'Message.Greeting'

        // JMESPath result
        'Hello'
```

#### Example 02

- In this example, we use JMESPath to query JSON. We get an unwanted result because we are querying against a JSON `string` element.

  - A more detailed description: We have a top-level json `object` with a single name-value pair.

    - The name in the name-value pair consists of the string "Message"
    - The value in the name-value pair consists of a JSON `string`

      - Digging deeper, the JSON `string` looks similar to a JSON object, but it is not a JSON object, because it follows the conventions of a JSON `string`

```js
        // Original JSON
        {
            "Message": "{\"Greeting\":\"Hello\",\"Audience\":\"World!\"}"
        }

        // JMESPath query 
        --query 'Message.Greeting'

        // JMESPath result
        None (null result)
```

### See also

- [JSON dot org](https://json.org)
- [related JSON question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)

  - [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383699/42223)