# Coding convention: Matching backend with frontend labels

Tags: frontend, backend, data-conversion, conventions

In my backend, I have data attributes labeled in camelcase:

```
customerStats: {
  ownedProducts: 100,
  usedProducts: 50,
},
```

My UI code is set up in a way that an array of ["label", data] works best most of the time i.e. most convenient for frontend coding. In my frontend, I need these labels to be in proper english spelling so they can be used as is in the UI:

```
customerStats: [
  ["Owned products", 100],
  ["Used products", 50],
],
```

My question is about best practices or standards in web development. I have been inconsistent in my past projects where I would convert the data at random places, sometimes client-side, sometimes right on the backend, sometimes converting it one way and then back again because I needed the JSON data structure.

**Is there a coding convention how the data should be supplied to the frontend?**

Right now all my data is transfered as JSON to the frontend. Is it best practice to convert the data to the form that is need on the frontend or backend? What if I need the JSON attributes to do further calculations right on the client?

Technologies I am using:

- Frontend: Javascript / React
- Backend: Javascript / Node.js + Java / Java Spring

Comment: Data structures should be converted to human readable labels as late as possible, usually just in the final HTML template (if applicable). When exactly the “latest” possible point is depends a lot of your specific app.

Comment: @deceze Yes, that's what I thought. Do you have a reference like a blog post or article for this statement that explains this in more detail? I would accept it as an answer then.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which technologies you are using for the front or back end, this information can greatly affect the response you will get.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I added the technologies: Frontend: Javascript / React. Backend: Javascript / Node.js + Java / Java Spring. I asked a general question and I expected a general answer. Your answer qas quite extensive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a coding convention for how to transfer data to the front end

If your front end is JavaScript based, then JSON *(Java Script Object Notation)* is the simplest form to consume, it is a *stringified* version of the objects in memory. [See this healthy discussion for more information on JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383692/1690217)

Given that the most popular front end development language is JavaScript these days, ([see the latest SO Survey on technology](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology)) It is very common and widely accepted to use JSON format to transfer data between the back and front end of solutions. The decision to use JSON in non-JavaScript based solutions is influenced by the development and deployment tools that you use, seeing more developers are using JavaScript, most of our tools are engineered to support JavaScript in some capacity.

It is however equally acceptable to use other structured formats, like XML.

JSON is generally more light-weight than XML as there is less provision made to transfer meta-data about the schema. For in-house data streams, it can be redundant to transfer a fully specced XML schema with each data transmission, so JSON is a good choice where the structure of the data is not in question between the sender and receiver.

XML is a more formal format for data transmission, it can include full schema documentation that can allow receivers to utilize the information with little or no additional documentation.

CSV or other custom formats can reduce the bytes sent across the wire, but make it hard to visually inspect the data when you need to, and there is an overhead at both the sending and receiving end to format and parse the data.

> Is it best practice to convert the data to the form that is need on the frontend or backend?

The best practice is to reduce the number of times that a data element needs to be converted. Ideally you never have to convert between a label and the data property name... This is also the primary reason for using JSON as the data transfer format.

Because JSON can be natively interpreted in a JavaScript front end, in a JavaScript front end we can essentially reduce conversion to just the server-side boundary where data is serialized/deserialized. There is in effect no conversion in the front end at all.

> How to refer to data by the *property name* and not the *visual label*

The general accepted convention in this space is to separate the concerns between the data model and the user experience, the view. Importantly the view is the closest layer to the user, it represents a given 'point of *view*' of the data model.

It is hard to tailor a code solution for OP without any language or code provided for context, in an abstract sense, to apply this concept means to not try and have the data model carry the final information about how the data should be displayed, instead you have another piece of code that provides the information needed to present the data.

In different technologies and platforms we refer to this in different ways but the core concept of separating the Model from the View or Presentation is consistently represented through these design patterns:

- [Exploring the MVC, MVP, and MVVM design patterns](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2926003/exploring-the-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-design-patterns.html)
- [MVP vs MVC vs MVVM vs VIPER](https://themindstudios.com/blog/mvp-vs-mvc-vs-mvvm-vs-viper/)

For OP's specific scenario, this might involve a mapping structure like the following:

```
customerStatsLabels: {
  ownedProducts: "Owned products",
  usedProducts: "Used products",
}
```

If this question is updated with some code around how the UI is constructed I will update this response with something more specific.

NOTE:

In JavaScript, objects are simply arrays of arrays, and as such it is very easy to tweak existing code that is based on arrays, into code based on objects and vice-versa.