# Update Json value by updating variable

Tags: javascript, json

```
var a = 0;
jsonArr = [{
   "count" : a
}]
a = 10;
console.log(jsonArr[0].count)
```

This doesn't update my JSON values, is there a solution or JSON objects allow no references?

Comment: ```jsonArr[0].count = 3;``` is this what you want?

Comment: FYI: this isn't JSON but just a plain javascript object. More info on JSON here: [What is JSON and what is it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: @Reyno also relevant: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131)

Answer (score 0):

The `json.count` variable gets assigned to the **value** of `0`, as `0` is a `number`, and numbers are **primitives**.

If you used a **non-primitive** type then the object would hold the **reference** and the code would work as expected if you edited the object you are referencing.

Just re-assigning `a` to a different variable will replace that reference in `a`, pointing to a different object.

See [this tutorial](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/) for more info on primitives vs non-primitives and by-value vs by-reference, or [this example](https://jsbin.com/jiweciyovo/edit?js,console) for code that works how you are expecting.

Comment: "*If you used a non-primitive type then the object would hold the reference and the code would work as expected.*" [No, it wouldn't](https://jsbin.com/xafonov/edit?js,console). Also, there is no int type in JavaScript. There is number (it's what `a` is) and BigInt.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about the int confusion, corrected my answer, thanks for pointing that out.

The object being referenced would have to have its internals edited, but it is still a reference. re-assigning a variable is different, will add clarity to the answer for that.