# Append dynamic checkboxes from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this JSON response code from my script:

```js
{
  "id": 159690,
  "name": "Product name",
  "categories": {
    "2068": "Category one",
    "1760": "Category two",
    // ...
  }
}
```

I want to append checkboxes to `#chkrole` the with value and name from the JSON response. Instead, my code is giving me the following error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/grab_product_next',
  data: form.serialize(),
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(resp) {
    $('input#name').val(name);

    var json = JSON.parse(resp.categories);
    var val = 0;
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    var option = json.map(x =>
      table.append($('<tr></tr>').append($('<td></td>').append($('<input>').attr({
        type: 'checkbox',
        name: 'chkRoles',
        value: x.chkName,
        id: 'chkrole' + val
      }))).append(
        $('<label>').attr({
          for: 'chkRoles' + val++
        }).text(x.chkName))));

    $('#chkrole').append(table);
  }
})
```

Comment: The error message tells you that your "JSON" is not "JSON".

Comment: Change `var json = JSON.parse(resp.categories);` -> `var json = resp.categories;`  (and probably give it a better name)

Comment: Remember:  [JSON is always a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: and you have `#chkrole` within the table DOM element that you are trying to create further you are appending the table to `#chkrole` which is super unclear. And moreover, you have unique `chkrole` ids created by incrementing val. What are you trying to do in this particular line `$('#chkrole').append(table);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you don't need to use `JSON.parse` - jQuery has already done that for you.

You can also simplify and improve the code by using a `template` to hold the HTML instead of creating some convoluted JS logic to build it. This is a better approach as it follows the Separation of concerns principle.

You should also avoid putting `id` attributes in dynamic HTML. You can instead wrap the `input` within the `label` and remove both the `id` and `for` attributes, like this:

```js
// mock AJAX response:
let resp = {
  "id": 159690,
  "name": "Product name",
  "categories": {
    "2068": "Category one",
    "1760": "Category two"
  }
}

// outside $.ajax success handler:
let rowTemplate = $('#table-row-template').html().trim();

// inside $.ajax success handler:
var rows = Object.entries(resp.categories).map(c => rowTemplate.replace(/{{id}}/gi, c[0]).replace(/{{name}}/gi, c[1]));
$('<table />').append(rows).appendTo('#chkRole');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chkRole"></div>

<template id="table-row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkRoles" value="{{id}}" />
        {{name}}
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```