# Create New array from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the below array

```
var firstjson = [
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 1",
                  "Product" : "Apple",
                  "Buy"     : "24",
                  "Sell"    : "20",
                  "Profit"  : "100",
                  "Lost"    : "20"
                 },
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 1",
                  "Product" : "Egg",
                  "Buy"     : "24",
                  "Sell"    : "20",
                  "Profit"  : "100",
                  "Lost"    : "20"
                 },
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 2",
                  "Product" : "Apple",
                  "Buy"     : "44",
                  "Sell"    : "10",
                  "Profit"  : "10",
                  "Lost"    : "200"
                 },
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 2",
                  "Product" : "Milk",
                  "Buy"     : "24",
                  "Sell"    : "20",
                  "Profit"  : "100",
                  "Lost"    : "20"
                 }
                ]
```

I'm trying to get out like below

```
var finalarray = [
                  {
                   "Week"    : "Week 1",
                   "Apple_Buy" : "24",
                   "Apple_Sell" : "20",
                   "Apple_Profit" : "100",
                   "Apple_Lost" : "20",
                   "Egg_Buy" : "24",
                   "Egg_Sell" : "20",
                   "Egg_Profit" : "100",
                   "Egg_Lost" : "20"
                  },
                  {
                   "Week"    : "Week 2",
                   "Apple_Buy" : "44",
                   "Apple_Sell" : "10",
                   "Apple_Profit" : "10",
                   "Apple_Lost" : "200",
                   "Milk_Buy" : "24",
                   "Milk_Sell" : "20",
                   "Milk_Profit" : "100",
                   "Milk_Lost" : "20"
                  },
                 ]
```

I tried first taking the week to an array then loop through each week and push value to new array like below

```
var Weeklist = [];
var dataSetarray = []
$.when(
    $.each(data, function(i,item){        
        Weeklist.push(data[i]['Week'])
    })
    ).then(function () {                      
        var uniqueWeeklist = Weeklist.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
            return i == Weeklist.indexOf(itm);
        });
        for(z = 0; z<uniqueWeeklist.length; z++){
            $.when(
                $.each(data, function(x,item){               
                    if(data[x]['ATD/ETD/RETD Week'] == uniqueWeeklist[z]){
                        dataSetarray.push({
                            "year" : uniqueWeeklist[z],
                          
                        })
                    }
                })
                ).then(function () {               
                            console.log(dataSetarray)    
                });
        }                
});
```

but was not able to continue after that maybe there is a shot way to loop through the first array itself and create the final array with out taking the weeks to another array?

Comment: *i have [below] json* - no, no you don't.   Start here:  [What is JSON (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: You can do a group by week using reduce. Then in the end take Object.values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely something you can do without jQuery.

I'd approach this in two steps...

1. Collect all the data into an object with the keys being the `Week` value and the values being an object with the `Product`-prefixed rest of the data
2. Convert that object into an array with the `Week` keys going back into the values

```js
// just your data minified
const firstjson = [{"Week":"Week 1","Product":"Apple","Buy":"24","Sell":"20","Profit":"100","Lost":"20"},{"Week":"Week 1","Product":"Egg","Buy":"24","Sell":"20","Profit":"100","Lost":"20"},{"Week":"Week 2","Product":"Apple","Buy":"44","Sell":"10","Profit":"10","Lost":"200"},{"Week":"Week 2","Product":"Milk","Buy":"24","Sell":"20","Profit":"100","Lost":"20"}];

// group
const groupByWeek = firstjson.reduce((map, { Week, Product, ...rest }) => {
  // initialise to an object if not set
  map[Week] ??= {};

  // merge in data
  Object.assign(
    map[Week],
    // map each key to be Product-prefixed
    ...Object.entries(rest).map(([key, val]) => ({
      [`${Product}_${key}`]: val,
    }))
  );

  return map;
}, {});

// convert to array
const finalarray = Object.entries(groupByWeek).map(([Week, data]) => ({
  Week,
  ...data,
}));

console.log(finalarray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all.. sorry for my messy code but it should be simple enough for you to understand. Some weakness which is please make sure your week 1 has unique product such that no repeated egg, apple and milk.

```js
var firstjson = [
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 1",
                  "Product" : "Apple",
                  "Buy"     : "24",
                  "Sell"    : "20",
                  "Profit"  : "100",
                  "Lost"    : "20"
                 },
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 1",
                  "Product" : "Egg",
                  "Buy"     : "24",
                  "Sell"    : "20",
                  "Profit"  : "100",
                  "Lost"    : "20"
                 },
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 2",
                  "Product" : "Apple",
                  "Buy"     : "44",
                  "Sell"    : "10",
                  "Profit"  : "10",
                  "Lost"    : "200"
                 },
                 {
                  "Week"    : "Week 2",
                  "Product" : "Milk",
                  "Buy"     : "24",
                  "Sell"    : "20",
                  "Profit"  : "100",
                  "Lost"    : "20"
                 }
                ]
var finalarray = []
var list = []
for(i = 0; i < firstjson.length; i++){
    list.push(firstjson[i].Week);
}

var unique = [...new Set(list)]

for(i = 0; i < unique.length; i++){
    tempjson = {};
    tempjson.Week = unique[i]
    for(j = 0; j < firstjson.length;j++){
        if(unique[i] == firstjson[j].Week){
            tempjson[firstjson[j].Product + "_Buy"] = firstjson[j].Buy
            tempjson[firstjson[j].Product + "_Sell"] = firstjson[j].Sell
            tempjson[firstjson[j].Product + "_Profit"] = firstjson[j].Profit
            tempjson[firstjson[j].Product + "_Lost"] = firstjson[j].Lost
        }
    }
    finalarray.push(tempjson);
}
console.log(finalarray)
```