# Merge array objects of different values in a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

I have 3 array objects-

```
dates = [{date: '12/04/2023'}, {date: '13/04/2023'}]
days = [{day: 'Monday'}, {day: 'Tuesday'}]
time = [{time: '09-10'}, {time: '10-11'}]
```

the final array should be like:

```
final = [
{
 date: '12/04/2023',
 day: 'Monday',
 time: '09-10'
},
{
 date: '13/04/2023',
 day: 'Tuesday',
 time: '10-11'
 }
]
```

I tried merging/concat the arrays and other solutions that I could find but couldn't find anything closer to my desired result.

I know there have been multiple questions on merging array objects but I haven't been able to find any solution that fits my requirement.

Any help would highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: why is 10-11 a day on 3rd array. also can use map and spread and access other arrays using index

Comment: sorry that was a typo , I have updated my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an object from an array of keys and an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127989/create-an-object-from-an-array-of-keys-and-an-array-of-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the index to access other arrays.

```js
const dates = [{date: '12/04/2023'}, {date: '13/04/2023'}]
const days = [{day: 'Monday'}, {day: 'Tuesday'}]
const time = [{time: '09-10'}, {time: '10-11'}]

const res = dates.map(({date},i) => ({date, day: days[i].day, time: time[i].time}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, would you able to explain the logic briefly. Thanks

Comment: @ankitjt which part you dont understand. map is used to transform an array. so here I'm transforming the dates array into an array of objects containing the other 2 fields as well. to get the other 2 fields i use the index which is available in map

Comment: @ankitjt hope this was clear. let me know if any other questions

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes,

```
dates = [{date: '12/04/2023'}, {date: '13/04/2023'}]
days = [{day: 'Monday'}, {day: 'Tuesday'}]
time = [{time: '09-10'}, {time: '10-11'}]
    
const result = dates.map((d,index) => {
    d.day = days[index].day;
    d.time = time[index].time;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please don't misuse `map` when you're not using the array it creates. If you just want a loop, just use a loop (or `forEach`). More in my post [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/). (But instead of doing `[...dates]` and then `map`, you could correctly using `map` on `dates`...) It's also probably worth making sure the OP understands this *modifies* the objects in the `dates` array, rather than creating new objects.

Comment: Yes, I checked your post and found much useful, Thank you for your suggestion :) I have updated my answer

Comment: You're still using `map` without using its return value. See cmgchess' answer for how you'd properly use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for loop` for simple reading and better performance

```js
dates = [{date: '12/04/2023'}, {date: '13/04/2023'}]
days = [{day: 'Monday'}, {day: 'Tuesday'}]
time = [{time: '09-10'}, {time: '10-11'}]

combined = []

for(i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
  combined.push({
  date: dates[i].date, 
  day: days[i].day, 
  time: time[i].time
  })
}

console.log(combined)
```

Also... there is this post that might help you with repeated date and you wanted to make it unique.
[Create New array from another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75808950/create-new-array-from-another-array/75809430#75809430)

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop.

```
const final = [];

for (let date = 0; date < dates.length; date++) {
  for (let day = 0; day < days.length; day++) {
    for (let t = 0; t < time.length; t++) {
      const tmp = {
        date: dates[date].date,
        day: days[day].day,
        time: time[t].time
      };
      result.push(tmp);
    }
  }
}

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @cmgchess has the best answer, 
Just wanted to share an interesting solution for this
by using `Array.prototype.reduce()` and the remainder of the array's index and the length of the array:

```js
const dates = [{date: '12/04/2023'}, {date: '13/04/2023'}];
const days = [{day: 'Monday'}, {day: 'Tuesday'}];
const time = [{time: '09-10'}, {time: '10-11'}];

const size = dates.length;
const res = [...dates, ...days, ...time].flat().reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[index % size] = {
    ...acc[index % size],
    ...curr
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```