# Mapping array values in javascript object with fixed keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

I want to create a javascript object such as below :

```
{
   {
    "Image" :  img_src,
    "Text" :   text
    },

}
```

I have two arrays

```
img_src = [ value1, value2, value3 ....... ]
text = [ text1, text2, text3 .......]
```

I want to map the values of these arrays in that object such that values of img_src is placed next to key "Image" and values of text is places next to key "Text" in the following manner:

```
{
   {
     "Image" : value1,
     "Text" : text1
   },
  {
     "Image" : value2,
     "Text" : text2
   },
  {
     "Image" : value3,
     "Text" : text3
   } 
}
```

and so on. I tried reading javascript documentation and tried all sort of things but I am unable to come up with a solution. Could someone kindly explain how can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use map and its index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75992506/merge-array-objects-of-different-values-in-a-new-object/75992552#75992552

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array of objects from multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539591/how-to-create-an-array-of-objects-from-multiple-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Either use a for loop to iterate over both arrays and construct an object from them or use the .map() function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want an array of objects as the output.  If so, you can map over one of the arrays, ex. `img_src`, and use a combination of items and indexes to generate each combined object.

```
let combined = img_src.map((img, index) => ({Image: img, Text: text[index]}));
```