# Javascript JSON.parse "0x" string strange conversion

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have the following json structure returned by an API:

```
{
    "data": {
        "artemis_ids": {},
        "symbols": {
            "0XBTC": {
                "price": 2.37
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use JSON.parse in Google apps script, the "0XBTC" string is somehow converted to number 11. See below the results of console.log:

```
console.log("content", content);
console.log("content json", JSON.parse(content));
```

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

```js
var content = `
    {
        "data": {
            "artemis_ids": {},
            "symbols": {
                "0XBTC": {
                    "price": 2.37
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

console.log("content", content);
console.log("content json", JSON.parse(content));
```

Comment: "*somehow*" - 0xB == 11

Comment: You could try encodeURIComponent

Comment: I've added your code as a snippet - it appears to work fine, so must be an issue specifically with [tag:google-apps-script]

Comment: Note that you have mixed up which is json and which is not - the plain string is *json* - the result of `JSON.parse(json_string)` is a javascript object *not* json.   Worth a read:  [what is JSON (stack overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for/383699#383699)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

From `content json {data={artemis_ids={}, symbols={11={price=2.37}}}}`, your showing log, I guessed that you might disable the V8 runtime with the script editor. But, when the V8 runtime is disabled, the backticks cannot be used. From this situation, also I guessed that your showing snippet might not be your actual script.

By supposing that my guess is correct, I tested the following sample script. And, I disabled the V8 runtime with the script editor.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var content = '{"data":{"artemis_ids":{},"symbols":{"0XBTC":{"price":2.37}}}}';

  console.log("content", content);
  console.log("content json", JSON.parse(content));
}
```

When this script is run without V8 runtime, the following result is obtained.

[image]

I confirmed that `console.log("content json", JSON.parse(content))` shows `content json {data={artemis_ids={}, symbols={11={price=2.37}}}}`. If my guess is correct, I think that this might be the reason for your current issue.

And also, when I tested the following script.

```js
function sample() {
  var content = '{"data":{"artemis_ids":{},"symbols":{"0XBTC":{"price":2.37}}}}';

  var sample1 = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(content));
  var sample2 = Object.keys(JSON.parse(content).data.symbols);

  console.log(sample1);
  console.log(sample2);
}
```

`console.log(sample1)` and `console.log(sample2)` are as follows.

```
{"data":{"artemis_ids":{},"symbols":{"11":{"price":2.37}}}}
```

and

```
[11]
```

From this situation, I guessed that this situation might be a bug or the current specification of Google Apps Script without V8 runtime. But, in the current stage, when the V8 runtime is disabled with the script editor, `"runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"` is added to the manifest file (`appsscript.json`). [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#automatic_migration_of_scripts_to_v8)

**In order to avoid this situation, as a simple solution, please enable V8 runtime with the script editor.** [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)

[image]

By this, the above script `sample()` returns as follows.

```
{"data":{"artemis_ids":{},"symbols":{"0XBTC":{"price":2.37}}}}
```

and

```
[ '0XBTC' ]
```

`0XBTC` is correctly used as the key.

#### Note:

If you are required to use your script by disabling the V8 runtime, how about using polyfill of JSON.parse? [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AB) When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

```js
function sample2() {
  // Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AB
  var rx_one = /^[\],:{}\s]*$/;
  var rx_two = /\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g;
  var rx_three = /"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g;
  var rx_four = /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g;
  var rx_dangerous = /[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g;
  JSON.parse = function (text, reviver) {

    // The parse method takes a text and an optional reviver function, and returns
    // a JavaScript value if the text is a valid JSON text.

    var j;

    function walk(holder, key) {

      // The walk method is used to recursively walk the resulting structure so
      // that modifications can be made.

      var k;
      var v;
      var value = holder[key];
      if (value && typeof value === "object") {
        for (k in value) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
            v = walk(value, k);
            if (v !== undefined) {
              value[k] = v;
            } else {
              delete value[k];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return reviver.call(holder, key, value);
    }

    // Parsing happens in four stages. In the first stage, we replace certain
    // Unicode characters with escape sequences. JavaScript handles many characters
    // incorrectly, either silently deleting them, or treating them as line endings.

    text = String(text);
    rx_dangerous.lastIndex = 0;
    if (rx_dangerous.test(text)) {
      text = text.replace(rx_dangerous, function (a) {
        return (
          "\\u" +
          ("0000" + a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)
        );
      });
    }

    // In the second stage, we run the text against regular expressions that look
    // for non-JSON patterns. We are especially concerned with "()" and "new"
    // because they can cause invocation, and "=" because it can cause mutation.
    // But just to be safe, we want to reject all unexpected forms.

    // We split the second stage into 4 regexp operations in order to work around
    // crippling inefficiencies in IE's and Safari's regexp engines. First we
    // replace the JSON backslash pairs with "@" (a non-JSON character). Second, we
    // replace all simple value tokens with "]" characters. Third, we delete all
    // open brackets that follow a colon or comma or that begin the text. Finally,
    // we look to see that the remaining characters are only whitespace or "]" or
    // "," or ":" or "{" or "}". If that is so, then the text is safe for eval.

    if (
      rx_one.test(
        text
          .replace(rx_two, "@")
          .replace(rx_three, "]")
          .replace(rx_four, "")
      )
    ) {

      // In the third stage we use the eval function to compile the text into a
      // JavaScript structure. The "{" operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity
      // in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text
      // in parens to eliminate the ambiguity.

      j = eval("(" + text + ")");

      // In the optional fourth stage, we recursively walk the new structure, passing
      // each name/value pair to a reviver function for possible transformation.

      return (typeof reviver === "function") ?
        walk({
          "": j
        }, "") :
        j;
    }

    // If the text is not JSON parsable, then a SyntaxError is thrown.

    throw new SyntaxError("JSON.parse");
  };


  var content = '{"data":{"artemis_ids":{},"symbols":{"0XBTC":{"price":2.37}}}}';

  var sample1 = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(content));
  var sample2 = Object.keys(JSON.parse(content).data.symbols);

  console.log(sample1); // <--- {"data":{"artemis_ids":{},"symbols":{"0XBTC":{"price":2.37}}}}
  console.log(sample2); // <--- [0XBTC]
}

sample2();
```

#### References:

- [Enabling the V8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Fantastic answer!Your assumption is correct, I'm using Rhino and cannot switch to V8 due to the infamous multiple accounts bug, so I'll go with your polyfill suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not a code issue, because it runs well at node@18 and Chrome@latest.

[image]