# How to iterate json object

Tags: jquery, object, each

I have the following json object and trying to iterate with jQuery each but it only returns one iteration. What am I not doing right?

```js
var data = "{
  "SIEcat4": {
    "3001": {
      "test": "test",
      "test": "test"
    },
    "3300": {
      "test": "test",
      "test": "test"
    }
  },
  "SIEcat5": {},
  "SIEcat6": {},
  "SIEcat13": {
    "3990": {
      "test": "test",
      "test": "test"
    }
  }
}"




$(JSON.parse(data)).each(function(key, value) {
  console.log("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: each is for arrays.. Also you have the same quotes wrapping the object and quoting the data. Newlines are only allowed in JS in a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or when you escape the newlines. So change the outer `"`  to `\`` and [find how to iterate nested object](https://www.google.com/search?q=iterate+nested+object+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please read: [What is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for) - there's no such thing as a "JSON Object" - you either have a JSON (string) or an Object.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment

$jQueryCollection.each() is normally used for jQuery collections - I would not use it for a nested object

[$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) can be used for objects but only one layer

Also you have the same quotes wrapping the object and quoting the data. Newlines are only allowed in JS in a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or when you escape the newlines. So change the outer `"`  to ` (bactick) and

[find how to iterate nested object](https://www.google.com/search?q=iterate+nested+object+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Lastly your object is invalid since it has more than one key named the same

Here is a working recursive iterator on a valid object - it can be used in jQuery if you insist

```js
const obj = JSON.parse(data);
const iterateObject = (obj, parentKey = '') => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      iterateObject(obj[key], `${parentKey}${key}.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${parentKey}${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
    }
  }
};

iterateObject(obj);

console.log('\n------\n');

// jQuery .each also needs the iterator
let parentKey = '';
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    iterateObject(obj[key], `${parentKey}${key}.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${parentKey}${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var data = `{
  "SIEcat4": {
    "3001": {
      "test1": "test",
      "test2": "test"
    },
    "3300": {
      "test1": "test",
      "test2": "test"
    }
  },
  "SIEcat5": {},
  "SIEcat6": {},
  "SIEcat13": {
    "3990": {
      "test1": "test",
      "test2": "test"
    }
  }
}`; 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your question your JSON object is wrapped in a string, that's not right. If you have a string representation of an object you will have to parse that as a separate step. If you have a real JSON object then you can use `Object.keys` to iterate over the keys of that object.

Also, jQuery is not needed at all for this.

Here's how you can loop over the keys and data in an object

```js
var data = {
  "SIEcat4": {
      "3001": {
          "test": "test",
          "test": "test"
      },
      "3300": {
          "test": "test",
          "test": "test"
      }
  },
  "SIEcat5": {},
  "SIEcat6": {},
  "SIEcat13": {
    "3990": {
        "test": "test",
        "test": "test"
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, '=>', data[key]);
});
```

If your data is a string representation of JSON data you can do the exact same thing as above, but you will need to run `JSON.parse` over it first to get the data out of the string.

```js
var dataAsString = `{
  "SIEcat4": {
      "3001": {
          "test": "test",
          "test": "test"
      },
      "3300": {
          "test": "test",
          "test": "test"
      }
  },
  "SIEcat5": {},
  "SIEcat6": {},
  "SIEcat13": {
    "3990": {
        "test": "test",
        "test": "test"
    }
  }
}`;

var data = JSON.parse(dataAsString);

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, '=>', data[key]);
});
```