# Why should we stringify the data to sent when posting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

When posting data to a controller from JavaScript:

```
async function createClient() {
  let response = await fetch($("#API_URL").val() + "/clients", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify($("#frmClient").serializeJSON()),
  });
  let data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

When I tried to use just `$("#frmClient").serializeJSON()`, which returns a JSON object, then the post failed. So why is it mandatory to stringify?

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Which part, even - why does the method return an object rather than a string? The short answer is simply because that's what the fetch API requires. You can look at the request body to see what it does by default and see why the recipient doesn't like it.

Comment: Please be sure to brush up on your terminology.  See this question [what is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for).

Comment: Please let us know *exactly* which plugin you are using for `seralizeJSON()` - there appear to be many with that name (a CDN or github link would suffice).  It's most likely the one you are using is actually returning *an object* and not JSON - hence the need to convert it to JSON with stringify.

Comment: @freedomn-m here is the site where I get the plugin : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/master/jquery.serializejson.js ; and here is the blog which has a link to it : https://medium.com/@mwakatumbula_/code-15ecdb18c2ef

Comment: From the github link in that source: *The serializeJSON function returns a JavaScript object, not a JSON String.* - you get an object, your API expects a *string* to you need to serialise it.  See answer by Quentin

Comment: Your issue is this *statement* "When I tried to use just $("#frmClient").serializeJSON(), which returns a JSON object" - searlizeJSON() does not return a JSON "object" (string), it returns a normal javascript object.  It's badly named even by the author's own admission.

Answer (score -1):

[There’s no such thing as a JSON object](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). You appear to be using [this plugin](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) which, contrary to its name, returns an object, not JSON.

You have to convert that object to JSON in order to have the request body be JSON.

Comment: Confirmed: literally on that link it states *The serializeJSON function returns a JavaScript object, not a JSON String. The plugin should probably have been called serializeObject or similar, but that plugin name was already taken.* - so the name they wanted wasn't available so they named it the opposite of what it does - that's not confusing ... at all.