# Build table row for each object & cell for each property

Tags: html, jquery, json

Trying to populate a table with JSON data. I'm new to JSON.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(users)) = 
[{
"fullname":"Bob Wirth",
"email":"Bob @mydomain.com",
"status":"A",
"lockcnt":"0",
"lastlogin":"2023-10-24 23:50:08.304896"
},{
"fullname":"Jane",
"email":"Jane@mydomain.com",
"status":"A",
"lockcnt":"0",
"lastlogin":"2023-11-03 11:31:57.18215"
}]
```

How do I build an each to iterate through each object and then each property so I can generate the tr tag on the object and td on the property.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please, update your question with the attempted code.

Comment: Read this first: [what is JSON and what is it used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: JSON lets you transfer data, that's pretty much it - you do not "iterate JSON" - you iterate the object that the JSON represents - in your case `users`.  No need for "JSON" here at all.   So `users.forEach((u) => $("#tbl").append("<tr><td>" + u.fullname + "</td></tr>"))`  (use interpolation / templates thiis just a quick example)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p8xu501z/

Comment: Please clarify how the Results should look. It's not clear where you might want headers or if there should be any grouping. It's not clear where the table should be returned in your HTML or what you want done with the table once created. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we don't make any assumptions, like you want the table to display the Keys as the Headers, then you will want to perform a loop with a nested loop. The first loop will create the Rows, from each element of the Array. The second loop will populate the Cells from the Object.

A basic example:

```js
$(function() {
  var users = [{
    "fullname": "Bob Wirth",
    "email": "Bob @mydomain.com",
    "status": "A",
    "lockcnt": "0",
    "lastlogin": "2023-10-24 23:50:08.304896"
  }, {
    "fullname": "Jane",
    "email": "Jane@mydomain.com",
    "status": "A",
    "lockcnt": "0",
    "lastlogin": "2023-11-03 11:31:57.18215"
  }];

  function makeTable(bodyData, target) {
    var $t = $("<table>");
    $.each(bodyData, function(key, row) {
      $("<tr>").appendTo($t);
      $.each(row, function(i, cell) {
        $("<td>").html(cell).appendTo($("tr:last", $t));
      });
    });
    if (target != undefined) {
      $(target).html($t);
    }
    return $t;
  }
  
  makeTable(users, "#results");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

From this, you could perform a lot of additional steps, for example, you could collect the Keys from one of the Objects and build headers for the Table.

There re also a lot of frameworks that can be used, like [Datatables](https://datatables.net/), that will do this all for you.