# Sending data from ajax to controller is not getting the value to the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to pass JSON data into MVC controller, which hasn't worked so far.

The controller method have the property as model like **newObject** like as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewObject newObject)
{
     try
     {
         //_deviceMangementService.CreateDevices(newObject.Name,1); // name is always null here
         return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
     }
     catch
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

The key point to solve this issue out there was to stringify the JSON object, define a model and get the parameter as the defined model, or define contentType. When it hits the controller i am getting null values in the name and DeviceId as 0.

I did those but defining a model for passing JSON into controller.

```
var newObject= {};
        newObject.DeviceId=1;
        newObject.Name = "testds";
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',         
     url: '@Url.Action("Create","DeviceConfiguration")',
     data: { newObject: JSON.stringify(newObject) },
     dataType: 'JSON',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     success: function (data) {
         if (data.success) {
             alert('Saved');;
         }
     },
     error: function (e) {
         console.log(e);
     }
 });
```

And i am getting the payload from network like

```
newObject=%7B%22DeviceId%22%3A1%2C%22Name%22%3A%22testds%22%7D
```

Is there another way to get JSON data from Ajax call in a controller or what i did wrong i don't know. Please guide me.

Comment: `data: { newObject: JSON.stringify(newObject) },` means your controller signature should be `public ActionResult Create(string newObject)` - you're passing a parameter with name newObject, but there isn't one on the action

Comment: "*Is there another way to get JSON data from Ajax call in a controller*" - don't mix up JSON (a string) and "data" (the original object).   If you want to pass *JSON* then receive a string (and parse it yourself) - if you want to pass *an object* then don't stringify it.

Comment: See this SO question/answer [what is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the data that is sent by ajax:

```
data: JSON.stringify(newObject)
```

so the controller can bind the properties in the model.