# How can I use a Json file in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, json

## Json in js

I made a js program that picks a "**advice number**" From 1-50.
It needs a way to connect with a json file.

**Js file:**

```
 Advice_number =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 ) + 1


console.log(Advice_number)
function Advice_picker() {


  
}
```

**Json file:**

```
[
    "When in the backrooms, keep your eyes low, for the walls have ears and the floors have eyes.",
    "Beware the flickering lights, for they are whispers of entities unseen.",
    "Navigate the endless halls with caution, for each turn may lead to another layer of despair.",
    "In the backrooms, silence is your ally. Speak softly, lest you awaken something that slumbers.",
    "Find solace in the quiet corners, but never linger for too long, for the stillness may consume you.",
    "Mark your path with care, for the backrooms shift and twist, leading even the most vigilant astray.",
    "Trust not the echoes, for they may lead you deeper into the labyrinth, where escape is but a fleeting dream.",
    "When all seems lost, seek the flicker of a distant light. But beware, for not all beacons lead to salvation.",
  ]
```

...

**I have more in the json file**

I tried looking for built-in functions but i couldn't find any.
my goal is that for the number it picks it logs a *random ***advice**.

If you know any functions that will help please tell me.

Comment: Where is this code being run? Also, please take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: I am running this code on vs code. and am using a site to see how the code logs.

Comment: @Roborou: Is this running on a web page in a browser?  On the command-line in NodeJS?  Something else?  If it's in a browser, can you make an AJAX call to the JSON file?

Comment: Worth a read: [What is JSON (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-what-is-it-used-for/383699#383699)

Comment: You can load your array using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: The answer will depend quite a bit on your enivronment. You can import the JSON file if you are using a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-data), or if you are using [JS modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). NodeJS has built-in support for CommonJS-style module loading via [require()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireid) which supports JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON files in Javascript like this.

```
    // Import the file system module
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    // Read the JSON file
    fs.readFile('data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading file:', err);
            return;
        }
    
        try {
            // Parse the JSON data
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    
            // Access the data from the JSON object
            const adviceArray = jsonData.advice;
    
            console.log(adviceArray);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can do this in Node.js, but not on client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript on client side, you can try with fetch.

```
fetch('data/data.json') // Adjust the path to match the location of your JSON file
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json(); // Parse JSON data from the response
    })
    .then(data => {
        // Access the data from the JSON object
        const adviceArray = data.advice;
        console.log(adviceArray);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching JSON:', error);
    });
```

Comment: You can set your data.json url in fetch() function.
In the above code, data JSON file is located in data directory.

Answer (score -1):

On client side you have to use `assert` as it is shown in [this article](https://medium.com/@akshaykrdas001/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-and-render-it-to-html-document-with-using-vanilla-javascript-a0191a894f25).
Also you have to use `type="module"` in the script tag in HTML document.

```js
import advices from "./path/to/data.json" assert { type: "json" };
const adviceNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 ) + 1;

console.log(adviceNumber);

function advicePicker() {
  return advices[adviceNumber];
}
```

Or you can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function, as it is also described in above mentioned article:

```js
const adviceNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 ) + 1;

fetch("./path/to/data.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data[adviceNumber]);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error loading JSON file", error));
```