# What exactly is this structure

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is this an object that contains objects or an array of objects?

```
var rgb = {
  ball: { Red: 232, Green: 23, Blue: 23},
  square: { Red: 42, Green: 83, Blue: 32},
};
```

I need to generate it with php and then declare it in my script, so want to know what I should be building in php

Comment: Looks more like [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: It only looks like JSON, but it does not entirely conform to the standard. For it to be real JSON, the IDs would have to be quoted.

Comment: @Will: JSON is derived from JavaScript, but *it is not* JavaScript.

Comment: @Martinho: Of course, but I mean that its syntax is a subset of that of JavaScript, and so to say it looks "more like" JSON doesn't really make sense. Besides, the code given here is *not* JSON.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+json

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286945/what-is-json)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an object, which contains two properties : `ball` and `square`.

Each one of these properties is an object, containing three properties *(`Red`, `Green`, and `Blue`)* -- which are numbers.

In Javascript :

- `{}` mean object : `{item1: 'value1', item2: 123}`
- and `[]` mean array : `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

From PHP, you can build the equivalent data-structure using something like this :

```
$data = (object)array(
    'ball' => (object)array('Red' => 232, 'Green' => 23, 'Blue' => 23), 
    'square' => (object)array('Red' => 42, 'Green' => 83, 'Blue' => 32), 
);
```

And, then, convert it to JSON with the [**`json_encode()`**](http://www.php.net/json_encode) function :

```
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
```

Comment: "This is an object" - <nitpicky>It's an object literal (+ declaration and assignment)</nitpicky> ;-)

Comment: You don't need the `(object)` cast. Associative arrays are always encoded as objects by default.

Comment: @Felix if you're only interested in the JSON result, true -- if you want to manipulate the data *(as an object)* on the PHP-side, you do.

Comment: I didn't thought about that... true.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Javascript object that contains other objects.

You should be able to generate it in PHP using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) and the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` parameter like so:

```
$rgb = new STDClass();
$rgb->ball = new STDCLass();
$rgb->square = new STDCLass();
$rgb->ball->Red = 232;
$rgb->ball->Green = 23;

// .... and so on

echo json_encode($rgb, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object with two properties, `ball` and `square` which are objects themselves. Both of them have the properties `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('ball'=>array('Red'=>232));
var_dump(json_encode($array));
```

This is only the short version. You should be able to add the other keys by yourself.

Because Javascript dont know associative arrays its not required to use objects here, because it will result into the same JSON-encoded string.